# Custom new project wizard with Xtext

Tags: eclipse, xtext, wizard

I use Xtext (`Eclipse: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2), Xtext: 2.12.0.v20170519-1412`). I've started with the standard example `org.xtext.example.mydsl`. Now I want to have a wizard in Eclipse for my DSL (like File → New → Project...). How do I do this? I found out by googling that I need to add this section to my MWE2 Workflow:

```
newProjectWizardForEclipse = {
            generate = true
         }
```

I did this, and I also get generated package `org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.wizard` with source files `MyDslProjectInfo.java`, `MyDslWizardNewProjectCreationPage.java` and `MyDslNewProjectWizardInitialContents.xtend`. However, if I start the new Eclipse runtime instance for MyDsl, there is no option for my own wizard (but other things work as expected, i.e. I can manually create a new `*.mydsl` file and it's correctly handled according to my grammar etc.)

What am I doing wrong or do I misunderstand something? Here is my complete `.mwe2` file.

```
module org.xtext.example.mydsl.GenerateMyDsl

import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.*
import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.model.project.*

var rootPath = ".."

Workflow {

    component = XtextGenerator {
        configuration = {
            project = StandardProjectConfig {
                baseName = "org.xtext.example.mydsl"
                rootPath = rootPath
                runtimeTest = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                eclipsePlugin = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                eclipsePluginTest = {
                    enabled = true
                }
                createEclipseMetaData = true
            }
            code = {
                encoding = "windows-1252"
                lineDelimiter = "\r\n"
                fileHeader = "/*\n * generated by Xtext \${version}\n */"
            }
        }
        language = StandardLanguage {
            name = "org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl"
            fileExtensions = "mydsl"

            serializer = {
                generateStub = false
            }
            validator = {
                // composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
            }

            // ---> I added this section, everyting else is standard example
            newProjectWizardForEclipse = {
               generate = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be that xtext cannot merge `plugin.xml` automatically. then a `plugin.xml_gen` is generated that you have to merge manually into `plugin.xml`

Comment: In fact, in the folder `org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui` I found a file `plugin.xml_gen`. I merged the difference into `plugin.xml` and now I have a new wizard item `MyDsl Project` under File → New → Project... → Xtext → MyDsl Project. Thanks a lot!